# Database.Migrate() raises SQL Server Express Login Failed Error

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm using EF Core version 2.1.11 with SQL Server Express version 12.0.2000.

I have my entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and my Db context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>();
    }
}
```

In order to create migrations using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`, I also have a design-time factory defined like:

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseSqlServer("server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyTestDB;Integrated Security=true")
            .Options;

        return new MyContext(options);
    }
}
```

Note that, in my SQL Express, I have not created a database named `MyTestDB`. I want EF Core to create this database and apply the migrations. So, my main method that attempts this is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContextFactory().CreateDbContext(Array.Empty<string>()))
        {
            ctx.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the line `ctx.Database.Migrate()` raises the exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "MyTestDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user
```

This exception is being raised because the `MyTestDB` is not in SQL Express server at the time of opening the connection. What is strange is, when I run the main method, it raises this exception like 15 times (which is suppressed unless the exception settings are enabled) but when the program exits, and I check the database, the database is actually created and the migrations are applied.

My question is how can I avoid this exception being raised (I do not want to create the database before running the code)? What is the proper way to use the connection string and the `Database.Migrate()` method?

Comment: Dont specificy the non existant db in the login string..

Comment: If I do that, I have to rebuild the connection string and update in the Db context to make sure that the queries work. Also, I'm not sure, if the `ctx.Database.Migrate` will work correctly without database not specified. The other downside to this is, the end users will have to change the way they supply connection strings. At the moment, this only is causing a problem in an integration test due to a timing issue. So, I'm trying to avoid any deep surgery like that.